# Assigning a function output to function parameter?

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP setup a predefined function parameter to be a result of another function?

```
function f1() { return rand().'entropy'; }

             #####
              ###
               #
function f2($a=f1(), $b=Null) {
    if($a==Null) $a='default';
    return $a.$b;
}
```

Comment: ... have you tried it to see?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Not even an error message about an unexpected '('?

Comment: Well, that could be matter of error handling setup. But, that's another topic and I wanted to present a generic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. . You can't assign it directly, but you can "*emulate*" it the same way you are doing with the "default" string:

```
function f1() { return rand().'entropy'; }

function f2($a = Null, $b=Null) {
    if ($a == Null) { $a = f1(); }
    if ($a == Null) { $a = 'default'; }
    return $a . $b;
}
```

. . Seeing that the `f1()` always returns a string, the second `if` in my code will never get executed. I just followed your code sample and as I understand this was just an example of how you can use the return of a function as a default value, ok?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: **The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.** - [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Diego. I'll guess PHP is not Python;]